# UIImage x-axis rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uiimage

I was able to rotate the UIImageView with the following code.

```
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 45.0 * .pi / 180.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
imageView.layer.transform = transform
```

[image]

Can I get a UIImage in the same state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your image to a CIImage and then apply the Core Image filter `CIPerspectiveTransform` to your image. A little googling found [**this article**](https://dzone.com/articles/a-look-at-perspective-transform-correction-with-co) on using that transform.

Comment: IF this answer solves your problem you should click the check-mark to accept it.